# Getting the default revision value when there is no revision attribute for project

Tags: python

INPUT:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<manifest>
<default revision="jb_2.5.4" remote="quic"/>
<project name="platform/vendor/google/proprietary/widevine"
         path="vendor/widevine"
         revision="refs/heads/jb_2.6"
         x-grease-customer="none"
         x-quic-dist="none"
         x-ship="none" />
<project path="external/dbus" name="platform/external/bus" revision="refs/heads/jb_2.5" x-ship="oss" x-quic-dist="la" x-grease-customer="none"/>

<project path="external/connectivity" name="platform/test/code" x-ship="oss" x-quic-dist="la" x-grease-customer="none"/>

</manifest>
```

Hi,

I have the following code which gets the revision value if it is present for the input shown above,if there is not "revision=" field it bails out with the error shown below..when there is no 
"revision=" tag I want to get the "default revsion" tag in the input..any inputs on how to do this withouth changing the existing functionality?

```
CODE:-

import shlex
import os
import sys
import json
import fileinput
import pwd
import itertools
import subprocess
import shutil
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import re

def manifest_data (name):
    print name
    pattern = re.compile('refs/heads/(.*)')
    tree = ET.parse('.repo/manifests/test.xml')
    root = tree.getroot()
    project = root.find("./project[@name='%s']" % name)
    print project
    if project != None:
        revision = project.get('revision')
        res = pattern.match(revision)
        return res.group(1)
    else:
        default = root.find("./default")
        return default.attrib.get('revision')

def main ():
    branch_name = "jb_mr2"
    print "branch_name"
    print branch_name
    projects = ['platform/vendor/google/proprietary/widevine','platform/external/bus','platform/test/code']
    #if os.path.isdir('.repo') :
        #print "Deleting .repo"
        #shutil.rmtree('.repo')
    RepoInitCmd =  'repo init -u git://git.quicinc.com/platform/manifest.git -b ' + branch_name
    proc = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(RepoInitCmd), stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    out, error = proc.communicate()
    for project in projects :
        branch = manifest_data(project)
        print branch

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

ERROR:-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "branch_manifest.py", line 45, in <module>
    main()
  File "branch_manifest.py", line 41, in main
    branch = manifest_data(project)
  File "branch_manifest.py", line 23, in manifest_data
    res = pattern.match(revision)
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

Comment: The error actually means that there is no even `project` tag with specified name. Could you show an example xml there you are seeing the error?

Comment: @alecxe - there is a project tag with "platform/test/code",the error is saying it doesnt have the "revision=" value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing `revision = project.get('revision')` with `project.attrib.get('revision', 'No revision')` should help.

UPD:

As you said `project` tag contains only `platform/test/code` attributes. In the line:

```
project = root.find("./project[@name='%s']" % name)
```

you are trying to find `project` tag by name. And it fails - `project` variable becomes `None` and the error is just correctly saying `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'attrib'`. Check `project` before trying to get the revision:

```
project = root.find("./project[@name='%s']" % name)
if project:
    revision = project.get('revision')
    res = pattern.match(revision)
    return res.group(1)
else:
    default = root.find("./default")
    return default.attrib.get('revision')
```

Comment: No it didnt,error again Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "branch_manifest.py", line 36, in <module>
    main()
  File "branch_manifest.py", line 32, in main
    branch = manifest_data(project)
  File "branch_manifest.py", line 19, in manifest_data
    revision = project.attrib.get('revision', 'No revision')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'attrib'

Comment: did it work for you?if project is not working because if you print "project"..you will see as <Element 'project' at 0x7feba1c4cb90> when it finds a name and 'None' if it doesnt

Comment: @alecxe..- I fixed it..but instead of returning "No revision" can we return "default revision=" value which is jb_2.5.4 in this case

Comment: thanks for your help..there is still one error as below when there is no revision attribute for project,I updated the question with the same.. name Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "branch_manifest.py", line 45, in <module>
    main()
  File "branch_manifest.py", line 41, in main
    branch = manifest_data(project)
  File "branch_manifest.py", line 23, in manifest_data
    res = pattern.match(revision)
TypeError: expected string or buffer

Answer (score 0):

The error given implies that `project` is `None` in this situation, so the most straightforward answer would be to verify that `project is not None` before you start trying to call methods on it. It looks like in this case you could just use a ternary:

```
revision = project.get('revision') if project is not None else some_default
```